# Use an imported font on PyGame

Tags: python-3.x, fonts, pygame

I want to add a font imported from google to Pygame.
I used that code but when I run script, the window immediately closes :

```py
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

myfont = pygame.font.Font("resources/fonts/Mansalva.zip", 30)
```

The path to my .zip font is also good.

Comment: *.zip* is an archive. Probably you've to unzip it and to load a single (*.ttf*) from the archive.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks, it works, I'm surprised that I need to unzip it.
Could you also post it as answer to get the post closed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*.zip* is an archive. You've to unzip it and to load a single (e.g. *.ttf*) file from the archive. The filename which is passed to [`pygame.font.Font`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font) is assumed to be a font file. A zip-archive file can't be processed an causes an exception.